# Microsoft text translator API issue when translating html content larger than 5000 characters

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-translator

https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0

I am using Microsoft text translator to translate the html content to other languages. As this API could process only 5000 characters at a time, I used Python to convert the large Html content to around 5k Caharacters chunks of data without breaking the html tags in half.

I am facing below issues while calling API with each chunk I splitted.

1. When I use "plain" as textType in the argument section, its even translating the meta tag information (like  Hello 
   to  Olá in Portuguese) which resulting formatting issue when handling large Html content.
2. When I use "html" as textType in the argument section, It is not translating the html meta tag information as unlike above one however its 
   automatically closing the tags at the end of the chunk whichiver opened in the each chunk. which is again causing the formatting issues.

Example : (For this example purpose I am chunking for each 5 lines)

````
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>ENAME</td>
<td>ENO</td>
<td>DEPTNO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bob</td>
<td>121</td>
<td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Aron</td>
<td>122</td>
<td>302</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>```

Chunk1:  <html><body><table><tr><td>ENAME</td> 
chunk2: <td>ENO</td><td>DEPTNO</td></tr><tr><td>Bob</td>
chunk3:  <td>121</td><td>300</td></tr><tr><td>Aron</td>
chunk4: <td>122</td><td>302</td></tr></table></body></html> 

I call API with each chunk and translate it into required language and in the end I concatanate all responses of all chunks(which will give the total translated html content).

chunk 1 processing
--------------------
<html><body><table><tr><td>ENAME</td> 
when I pass above string to API bleow response I am receiving
<html><body><table><tr><td>Ename</td></tr></table></body></html>

It's automatically closing the tr,table,body and html which is not at all my intention, as it will be closed 4th chunk when I call API with it.
As it's automatically closes the tags in the first chunk itself instead of waiting till 4th chunk, resulting the formatting issue.

Could you please let me know how to hanlde this issue without having formatting issues.

Looking forward for the fast response!!

Thank you!!
````

Answer (score 1):

Translator in HTML mode requires a complete element to be passed in. It doesn't matter what that element is:
Parse to the closing tag
if (element <= 5000 chars) Translate(element);
else process each child element recursively.

Example in C# using the HTML Agility Toolkit to parse:
https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslator/blob/master/TranslationAssistant.Business/HTMLTranslationManager.cs